# django login without request

Tags: python, django, authentication, request

I want to authenticate a user via api which will gives username and password in kwargs. In my login view I want to call this function. In my view I just want to render the template not logics to put.

```
def login(**kwargs):
    user = authenticate(username=kwargs['username'], password=kwargs['password'])
    login(user)
```

In django registration tutorial i am seeing `login(request, user)` .
I am confused that should i use `request` in here or it will be logged in without user.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Django's `login` function that you call inside your own function takes the request. There is no way to call it without that parameter. This of course makes sense, as there is *no possible reason* to be logging a user in outside of the context of a request.

Comment: should I put request in my in my own function too like def login(request, **kwargs):

Answer (score 0):

To log a user in *i.e.* to set a session, you will need `request` parameter. Note that you can't name your function `login` because it will conflict with Django's `login` function.

If you just want to separate logic and template, you can do this:

```
def my_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # process logic
        # authenticate user
        return HttpResponse('some message')
    # the following code is processed when
    # request.method is not POST
    return render(request, 'login-template.html')
```